# Regards to DDoS attack

Tags: discussion, security

I am new to Stack Overflow (account created yesterday) and it's first time I have seen Stack Overflow suffer. More specifically, it's first time ever not being able to access Stack Overflow when I needed some support from you guys.

We now know what the problem is and we also know what had caused this website to be temporarily inaccessible. Are there any other types of attack this website has suffered other than DDoS?

Just curious...

Comment: When I asked 'Does it wait and hoping that DDoS attack will go away?', 'Does it simply wait until everything settles down?', I didn't mean to sound like admins are doing nothing. I am sure they are working hard against time and do everything to recover as soon as possible. Out of those question, I am more interested in 'How does it recover?', 'What immediate actions are taken after the website is recovered?', 'Other types of attack this website has suffered other than DDoS', and of course, statistical figure.

Comment: And I don't understand why I am getting downvoted? Did I ask something that I shouldn't have?

Comment: @random Thing is that people who sees this question don't have to provide too detailed and broad answers. Yes there may be too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format but it's possible for people to give short yet enough detailed answer for me and others to think about other possible reasons.

Comment: Only the Stack Exchange team could answer this meaningfully, and it seems unlikely that they will share details about how exactly they deal with an attack that may still be ongoing. It's probably more productive to look for information how DDOSs are dealt with generally - but that would be off topic here.

Comment: Re how often this happens, to my knowledge it was the first time. You can see the site's status messages here: https://www.stackstatus.net

Comment: If the SE team were going to post a post mortem on this it would be posted on the blog

Comment: I've pretty much edited almost everything. I'm sure it's not too broad nor too long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a DDoS is thankfully a temporary issue(although it can reoccur weekly, etc). The nature of DDoS is that it's like a digital-tornado almost. Basically, it requires directed effort that needs people to carry it out.

But DDoS, if the enemy was *really* intent, could last many hours.

See this post - [How long do DDoS attacks last?](https://serverfault.com/questions/98154/how-long-do-ddos-attacks-last)

this is good too:

[I am under DDoS. What can I do?](https://serverfault.com/questions/531941/i-am-under-ddos-what-can-i-do)

What happens is that the network admins try to block off specific routes in the Internet. You try to locate where the traffic emanates from, block certain servers. etc

As for :

> Are there any other types of attack this website has suffered other than DDoS?

Some of this would be under wraps, but you always block SQL injection stuff. I'm sure they sanitize JS also, use Caja or such.

But DDoS is the major issue